# PHP using preg_replace on every number in string

Tags: php, regex

Say I have a multiline string like

```
A: 51
B: 221
C: 45
```

And I want to replace it to get

```
A: $51
B: $221
C: $45
```

I tried

```
preg_replace("/[\d*][^0-9]*/","$currency$0",$pricelist);
```

but that prepends the currency symbol before every digit instead of every number. I also tried

```
preg_replace("/[\d]*/","$currency$0",$pricelist);
```

but that surrounds the amount with two currency symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `+` quantifier instead of `*`:

```
preg_replace("/\d+/", "$currency$0",$pricelist);
```

Using `*` quantifier, your regex first matches all the digits, and then matches the empty string after the last digit. Hence you see two `$` symbols - One before the digits matched, and one before the empty string matched after last digit.